# How to solve $a \cdot x^{2} + b \cdot x + c + \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) = 0$ for $x$ where $x \in \mathbb{C} \cup \{ \hat{\infty} \}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, lambert-w

##### General

Question: How to solve $a \cdot x^{2} + b \cdot x + c + \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) = 0$ for $x$ where $x \in \mathbb{C} \cup \left\{ \hat{\infty} \right\} \wedge \left\{ a,\, b,\, c,\, d,\, e \right\} \in \mathbb{C}$ (note: here $e$ is not euler's constant)?

Backgrund: When I sometimes calculate with ODEs, I sometimes come across equations of this form. So I'm wondering what a general solution to this would look like?

##### My Trys

Since I've often encountered such equations, I've tried a few things accordingly. I'll just name the best (for non-trivial stuff):

###### If $a = 0$

$$
\begin{align*}
0 \cdot x^{2} + b \cdot x + c + \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) &= 0\\
b \cdot x + c + \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) &= 0\\
\exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) &= -c - x \cdot b\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
-x \cdot b - c &= \exp\left( e - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} + x \cdot d + \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right)\\
-x \cdot b - c &= \exp\left( e - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} + x \cdot d + \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right)\\
-x \cdot b - c &= \exp\left( e - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) \cdot \exp\left( x \cdot d + \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
-x \cdot b \cdot \exp\left( -x \cdot d - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) - c \cdot \exp\left( -x \cdot d - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) &= \exp\left( e - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right)\\
-x \cdot d \cdot \exp\left( -x \cdot d - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \cdot \exp\left( -x \cdot d - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) &= \frac{d}{b} \cdot \exp\left( e - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right)\\
\left( -x \cdot d - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) \cdot \exp\left( -x \cdot d - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) &= \frac{d}{b} \cdot \exp\left( e - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
-x_{k} \cdot d - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} &= W_{k}\left( \frac{d}{b} \cdot \exp\left( e - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) \right)\\
x_{k} + \frac{c}{b} &= -\frac{1}{d} \cdot W_{k}\left( \frac{d}{b} \cdot \exp\left( e - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) \right)\\
x_{k} &= -\frac{1}{d} \cdot W_{k}\left( \frac{d}{b} \cdot \exp\left( e - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) \right) - \frac{c}{b}\\
\end{align*}
$$

$$\fbox{$x_{k} = -\frac{1}{d} \cdot W_{k}\left( \frac{d}{b} \cdot \exp\left( e - \frac{c \cdot d}{b} \right) \right) - \frac{c}{b}$}$$

Where $W_{k}$ is the Lambert W Function...

###### If $a \ne 0$

**Completing ...**
$$
\begin{align*}
a \cdot x^{2} + b \cdot x + c + \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) &= 0\\
a \cdot x^{2} + b \cdot x + \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) &= -c\\
a \cdot x^{2} + b \cdot x + \frac{b^{2}}{4} + \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) &= -c + \frac{b^{2}}{4}\\
a \cdot x^{2} + b \cdot x + \frac{b^{2}}{4} + \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) &= -c + \frac{b^{2}}{4}\\
x^{2} + \frac{b}{a} \cdot x + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a^{2}} + \frac{1}{a} \cdot \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) &= -\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a^{2}}\\
\left(x + \frac{b}{2 \cdot a} \right)^{2} + \frac{1}{a} \cdot \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) &= -\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a^{2}}\\
\end{align*}
$$
Fail: I can't think of anything useful to add.

**Substitution + Compliting ...**
$$
\begin{align*}
\left(\underbrace{x + \frac{b}{2 \cdot a}}_{= u} \right)^{2} + \frac{1}{a} \cdot \exp\left( d \cdot x + e \right) &= -\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a^{2}}\\
u^{2} + \frac{1}{a} \cdot \exp\left( d \cdot \left( u - \frac{b}{2 \cdot a} \right) + e \right) &= -\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a^{2}}\\
u^{2} + \frac{1}{a} \cdot \exp\left( d \cdot u - \frac{d \cdot b}{2 \cdot a} + e \right) &= -\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a^{2}}\\
\frac{1}{a} \cdot \exp\left( d \cdot u - \frac{d \cdot b}{2 \cdot a} + e \right) &= -\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a^{2}} - u^{2}\\
\exp\left( d \cdot u - \frac{d \cdot b}{2 \cdot a} + e \right) &= -c + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a} - a \cdot u^{2}\\
\exp\left( d \cdot u + f - \frac{d \cdot b}{2 \cdot a} + e - f \right) &= -c + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a} -  a \cdot u^{2}\\
\exp\left( d \cdot u + f \right) \cdot \exp\left( -\frac{d \cdot b}{2 \cdot a} + e - f \right) &= -c + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a} -  a \cdot u^{2}\\
\exp\left( -\frac{d \cdot b}{2 \cdot a} + e - f \right) &= \left( -c + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a} -  a \cdot u^{2} \right) \cdot \exp\left( -d \cdot u - f \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
Fail: Nothing to simplify...

**Despair**
$$
\begin{align*}
\exp\left( -\frac{d \cdot b}{2 \cdot a} + e - f \right) &= \left( -c + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a} -  a \cdot u^{2} \right) \cdot \exp\left( -d \cdot u - f \right)\\
-\frac{d \cdot b}{2 \cdot a} + e - f &= \ln\left( \left( -c + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a} -  a \cdot u^{2} \right) \cdot \exp\left( -d \cdot u - f \right) \right)\\
-\frac{d \cdot b}{2 \cdot a} + e - f &= \ln\left( -c + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a} -  a \cdot u^{2} \right) + \ln\left( \exp\left( -d \cdot u - f \right) \right)\\
-\frac{d \cdot b}{2 \cdot a} + e - f &= \ln\left( -c + \frac{b^{2}}{4 \cdot a} -  a \cdot u^{2} \right) - d \cdot u - f \\
\end{align*}
$$

So there might be a solution in terms of Wright Lambert W functions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Single Sum:**

We solve:
$$a x^2 + b x + c + \exp(d x + e)=0\iff \exp(-dx)\left(x^2+\frac ba x+\frac ca\right)=-\frac{\exp(e)}a$$

From this point on, $e$ is euler’s constant:

$$e^{-dx}(x+p)(x+q)=r\mathop\iff^{x=t-p} e^{-d(t-p)}(t-p+p)(t-p+q)=e^{-dt+dp} t(t-p+q)=e^{dp}e^{-dt} t(t-p+q)=r$$

Multiply both sides by $e^{-dp}$ and use [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem):

$$e^{-dt}t(t-p+q)=re^{-dp}\iff t=\frac{r e^{dt}}{e^{dp}(t+q-p)}=\frac{u e^{dt}}{(t+v)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{u^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(\frac{e^{dw}}{w+v}\right)\right|_0$$

Using general Leibniz rule:

$$\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(\frac{e^{dw}}{w+v}\right)\right|_0=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1}k\left.\frac{d^{n-1-k}e^{dnw}}{w^{n-1-k}}\right|_0\left.\frac{d^k(x+v)^{-n}}{dw^k}\right|_0$$

and [sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28-1%29%5Ek+%28d+n%29%5E%28-1+-+k+%2B+n%29+u%5En+%28v%29%5E%28-k+-+n%29+%CE%93%28k+%2B+n%29%29%2F%28%CE%93%281+%2B+k%29+%CE%93%281+%2B+n%29+%CE%93%28-k+%2B+n%29%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cn-1%7D%5D) to get [Bessel $\operatorname K_v(z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BesselK). Therefore:

$$\boxed{e^{-d t}t(t+v)=u\implies t=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{-dvn}(dn)^{n-1}}{n!e^\frac{dvn}2}\left(\frac uv\right)^n\operatorname K_{\frac12-n}\left(-\frac{dvn}2\right)}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28-t%2Fbaxter%29+t+%28t-4%29-catalan%2Ct%3Dsum%5B%282%5E%281+-+2+n%29+%28baxter%29%5E%281%2F2+-+n%29+Catalan%5En+e%5E%28%282+n%29%2Fbaxter+-+i+n+%CF%80%29+n%5E%28-1%2F2+%2B+n%29+BesselK%281%2F2+-+n%2C+%282+n%29%2Fbaxter%29%2F%28sqrt%28%CF%80%29+%CE%93%281+%2B+n%29%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C40%7D%5D)

**$j$th Complex Solution:**

$$a x^2 + b x + c + \exp(d x + e)=0\iff \exp(-dx)\left(x^2+\frac ba x+\frac ca\right)=\exp(-d x)(x^2+A x+B)=C$$

From this point on, $e$ is euler’s constant. Use an $x=t-\frac A2$ [Tshirnhaus transformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschirnhaus_transformation):

$$e^{-d t+\frac{Ad}2}\left(t^2-\frac{A^2}4+B\right)=C\iff e^{-d t} \left(t^2-\frac{A^2}4+B\right)=C e^{-\frac{Ad}2}$$

Solve for $t$ and use the complex logarithm where $j\in\Bbb Z$:

$$t=-\frac1d\ln\left(\frac{e^{-\frac{Ad}2}C}{t^2-\frac{A^2}4+B}\right)-\frac{2\pi i j}d=r \ln\left(\frac p{t^2-q}\right)+2\pi i jr=2\pi i j r+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{r^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}\ln^n\left(\frac p{t^2-q}\right)\right|_{2\pi i j r}$$

Using [Stirling S1](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/) and binomial theorem:

$$\frac1{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}\ln^n\left(\frac p{t^2-q}\right)\mathop=^{\left|\frac p{t^2-q}-1\right|<1}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{S_k^{(n)}}{k!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}\left(\frac p{t^2-q}-1\right)^k= \sum_{k=n}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^k\frac{S_k^{(n)}}{k!}(-1)^{k-m} p^m\binom k m \frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}((t-\sqrt q)(t+\sqrt q))^{-m}$$

[shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5B-2+%CF%80i+0.3%2Bsum%5Bsum%5Bsum%5B%28-0.3%29%5En%2F%28k%2Bn%29%21+StirlingS1%5Bk%2Bn%2Cn%5D+binom%28k%2Bn%2Cm%29%28-1%29%5E%28k%2Bn-m%29%28-0.7%29%5Em+D%5B%28y%5E2%2B3+i%29%5E-m%2C%7By%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C30%7D%5D%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+30%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D%2Cy-%3E-2*%CF%80*0.3*%E2%88%9A-1%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-exp%28-t%2F0.3%29-0.7%2F%28t%5E2%2B3i%29%2Ct%3D+0.504751+-+1.95966+i). We [evaluate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5B%28t%5E2-%CF%80%29%5E-%285.4%29%2C%7Bt%2C8-1%7D%5D-%28-sqrt%28q%29+%2B+t%29%5E%28-m%29+%28sqrt%28q%29+%2B+t%29%5E%281+-+m+-+n%29+%28%28-1%29%5E%281+%2B+n%29+%CE%93%28-1+%2B+m+%2B+n%29%29%2F%CE%93%28m%29+2F1%28m%2C+1+-+n%2C+2+-+m+-+n%2C+-%28sqrt%28q%29+%2B+t%29%2F%28sqrt%28q%29+-+t%29%29%2Ct%3D0.7%2Cn%3D8%2Cm%3D5.4%2Cq%3D%CF%80) $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}(t^2-q)^{-m} $ with the [Gauss hypergeometric function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2F1), expressible with [Legendre P](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0014/) for very specific values. Finally, [use](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/12/) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{k=n}^\infty a_{k,n}=\sum_ \limits{k=1}^\infty\sum \limits_{n=0}^ka_{k,n}$:

$$\boxed{e^{-d t}(t^2-q)=p\implies t_j=\frac{2\pi i j}d+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^k\sum_{m=0}^k\frac{S_k^{(n)}\Gamma(m+n-1)(-1)^{n+k+1}p^m r^n}{(k-m)!\Gamma(m)m!\left(\frac{2\pi i j}d+\sqrt q\right)^{n-1}\left(\left(\frac{2\pi j}d\right)^2+q\right)^m}\,_2F_1\left(m,1-n;2-m-n;\frac{4\pi j}{2\pi j+id\sqrt q}-1\right)}$$

where if the indices’ upper bound is $\infty$, the sums are interchangeable. As $j\to\infty$, the sum converges more gradually.

Comment: I have a question: where does the $\color{Red}{ e^{-d \cdot p}}$ come from in the RHS in $e^{-d \cdot x}\left( x + p \right) \cdot \left( x + q \right) = r \overset{x = t - p}{\Leftrightarrow} e^{-d \cdot t} t \cdot \left( t - p + q \right) = r \cdot {\color{Red}{ e^{-d \cdot p}}}$? That doesn't look right to me because if we multiply both sides by $e^{d \cdot x}$ we get $t \cdot \left( t - p + q \right) = r$ which is not true.

Comment: @KevinDietrich The steps are $e^{-dx}(x+p)(x+q)=r$. Now take $x=t-p: e^{-d(t-p)}(t-p+p)(t-p+q)=e^{-dt+dp} t(t-p+q)=e^{dp}e^{-dt} t(t-p+q)=r$. From this step, multiply both sides by $e^{-dp}$ to get $e^{-d t}t (t-p+q)=r e^{-d p}$. Does this help?

Answer (score 3):

$$a \, x^{2} + b \, x + c + \exp\left( d \, x + e \right)=0 $$

Let
$$x=\frac{t-e}{d}\qquad A=-\frac{a}{d^2}\qquad B=\frac{2 a e-b d}{d^2}\qquad C=-\frac{a e^2}{d^2}+\frac{b e}{d}-c$$
to make
$$e^t=A\,t^2+B\,t+C$$

Let $(r_1,r_2)$ be the roots of the quadratic
$$e^t=A(t-r_1)(t-r_2)\quad \implies \quad e^{-t}=\frac 1 A \frac 1{(t-r_1)(t-r_2)}$$ which is in the form of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).