# Integral representation for reverse Bessel polynomials

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions, contour-integration, bessel-functions, z-transform

$\DeclareMathOperator ZZ$Series solutions to partly invert [$e^x(x^2+a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849683/lagrange-b%C3%BCrmann-inversion-series-example/1179542#1179542) and [$e^xx(x+a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702756/how-to-solve-a-cdot-x2-b-cdot-x-c-exp-left-d-cdot-x-e-right/4702796#4702796) exist when more general quadratic-exponential equations are reduced. Using the [reverse Bessel polynomials $p_n(x)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselPolynomial.html):

$$e^xx(x+a)=b\implies x=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-2 ba^{-2})^n}{nn!}p_n\left(\frac{a n}2\right)\tag1$$

The [inverse Z transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Inverse_Z-transform), like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678992/convert-frac1b-sum-n-1-infty-fracb-eannb-n-1an-to-integral-us/), lets us find an integral representation by looking at the generating function:

$$\begin{align}\Z_x(p_n(x))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{p_n(x)}{n!}w^n=e^{(1-\sqrt{1-2w})x}\\ \implies p_n(x)=\Z^{-1}\left(e^{(1-\sqrt{1-2w})x} \right)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i }\oint\exp((1-\sqrt{1-2w})x)w^{-n-1}dw\\\mathop=^?\frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \exp\left(\left(1-\sqrt{1-2e^{it}})x-i t n\right)\right)dt\tag2\end{align}$$

This would allow an integral representation of $(1)$, but $(2)$ does not numerically match $p_n(x)$.

What is an actual integral representation for $p_n(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate
\begin{equation}
 x=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-2 ba^{-2})^n}{nn!}p_n\left(\frac{a n}2\right)
\end{equation}
one can use the expression for the [reverse Bessel polynomials $p_n(x)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselPolynomial.html) in term of the modified Bessel function eq. (2):
\begin{align}
 p_n(z)&=z^ny_{n-1}\left( \frac1z \right)\\
 y_n(z)&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}e^{1/z}K_{-n-1/2}\left( \frac 1z \right)
\end{align}
with $u=-2a^{-2}b$ and $X_n=an/2$ we have then
\begin{equation}
 x=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{u^n}{nn!}X_n^{n+1/2}e^{X_n}K_{-n+1/2}(X_n)
\end{equation}
The integral representation ([DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E11))
\begin{equation}
K_{\nu}\left(sz\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\nu+\frac{1}{2}\right)(2z)^{\nu}}{\pi%
^{\frac{1}{2}}s^{\nu}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(st\right)\,\mathrm{d}t}
{(t^{2}+z^{2})^{\nu+\frac{1}{2}}}
\end{equation}
is valid when $\nu>-1/2,s>0,\Re z>0$.

As $K_{-n+1/2}(X_n)=K_{n-1/2}(X_n)$, taking $z=1,s=X_n$ and after simplifications it comes
\begin{equation}
 x=-\frac{a}{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2ue^{a/2})^n}{n}\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(nat/2)}{(1+t^2)^n}\,dt
\end{equation}
and, by swaping summation and integration,
\begin{equation}
 x=-\frac{a}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\,dt\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \left( \frac{2ue^{a/2}}{1+t^2}\right)^n\cos(nat/2)
\end{equation}
Obtained series corresponds to the [generating function of the Tchebyshev polynomials](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.12.E9)
\begin{equation}
 -\ln\left(1-2xz+z^{2}\right)=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{T_{n}\left(x\right)}{n}%
z^{n}
\end{equation}
which is valid when $|z|<1$. With
\begin{equation}
 M=\frac{4b}{a^2}e^{a/2}
\end{equation}
one obtains
\begin{equation}
 x=\frac{a}{4\pi}\int_0^\infty\ln\left( 1+2M\frac{\cos(at/2)}{1+t^2}+\frac{M^2}{(1+t^2)^2} \right)\,dt
\end{equation}
This integral converges for any values of $M$ which makes the result correct for any values of the parameters $a\ne0$ and $b$. It can be numerically checked that this value of $x$ verifies
\begin{equation}
 xe^x\left( x+a \right)=b
\end{equation}

Comment: Do you know why the inverse Z transform integral did not work?

Comment: I think that there is a branch cut in the definition of the function from $w=1/2$, due to the square root. Then one cannot integrate along the unit circle without taking it into account.

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know where the integral representation comes from; for example, whether it be the result of a Fourier transform?

Comment: In Watson's book, Basset's integral is derived from a modification of Hankel's contour integral for the Bessel function (§6.11 and 6.16). Equivalence with other integral representations are given in $6.32 and 6.33. There is no explicit mention of Fourier transform.